# Switch between panes in VIM for codepen.io?

Tags: vim, codepen

When using vim mode in codepen.io, how do you switch between panes as ctrl+w+w doesn't work as it closes the window tab. What other codepen.io specific key bindings are there?

Answer (score 1):

It'd probably be better to ask the project maintainers, but it does not seem like it's possible. There's a whole page on their [blog post](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/editor/key-bindings/) that hints as to why. It also has a link to the project providing that functionality.